# Include an angular module in all.spec files via karma

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular1.6, angular-unit-test

I have an angular module that has some angular configuration that I want all tests to have before running. I could go in all the files and include that module via `angular.mock.module` but I was wondering if I could do it via karma somehow.

Answer (score 0):

make a new file with a suitable name. lets say `required.ts`. in this file, include all the required modules/dependencies which you want to include in your tests.
Now in `karma.conf`, add the `required.ts` in files and preprocess it to get the desired result.

you could also decide to make a `require.js` in which case you would not have to preprocess it in `karma.conf`.